# Axios Multiple requests to return different object values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a Film grid that return their Id, thumbnail, title, episode number and released date.

How can I display the Object Values on each specific view of species.names?

getSpecies() it returns object value but how can i passed them in render method?

**DetailFilms.js Component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class DetailFilms extends Component {
  state = {
    film: null,
    specie: null,
  }

  getFilms() {
    let id = this.props.match.params.films_id;
    return axios.get('https://swapi.co/api/films/' + id)
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          film: res.data
        })
        // console.log(res)
      })
  }

  getSpecies() {
    let id = this.props.match.params.films_id;
    return axios.get('https://swapi.co/api/species/' + id)
      .then((res) => {
        const species = res.data;
        const keys = Object.keys(species)
        console.log(species)
        this.setState({
          species: res.data.results,
          keys: keys
        })
      })
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getFilms();
    this.getSpecies();
  }
  render() {
    const film = this.state.film ? (
      <div className="jumbotron">
        <h2 className="display-4">{this.state.film.title}</h2>
        <p className="lead">{this.state.film.director}</p>
        <hr className="my-4" />
        <p>{this.state.film.producer}</p>
        <p>Episode Nº: {this.state.film.episode_id}</p>
        <p className="font-italic">{this.state.film.opening_crawl}</p>
        <p>Species: {this.state.film.species.name}</p>
        <Link className="btn btn-primary btn-lg" to="/" role="button">Character</Link>
      </div>
    ) : (
      <div className="spinner-border" role="status">
        <span className="sr-only">Loading...</span>
      </div>
    )
    return (
      <div className="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center ">
        {film}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default DetailFilms;
```

[CodeSandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/91ykownpqw) & [Api Documentation Swapi](https://swapi.co/)

Comment: `axios.get` does not return a value, thus your `getSpecies()` call will always return nothing..  Axios is a promise-based API.  For usage see: https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 2):

The props you are passing in with the route, it is called `films_id` not `species_id`.

So in your `getSpecies` method, this is how you should get the id of the current movie:

`let id = this.props.match.params.films_id;`

Then if you see the `species` api: https://swapi.co/api/species/

if you query it through the id, you will get the specie corresponding to that id, which is not the species of that movie.

In order to get all the species of that movie, you need to do an HTTP get request to the root `https://swapi.co/api/species/` and then check all the results which have as film the one for which you are seeing the details. These will be all the species of that movie.

Comment: Thks! But how can i pass in render method species.name values?

Comment: in that species field, what do you want to display? in general all the species, or all the species of that movie?

Comment: All the species of that movie

Comment: this is an example of how you display them, but you need to query also the other pages because all the species are 37, and the api returns 10 results for each page: https://codesandbox.io/s/o4j7j1m94q
I just did for the first page to show you how to do it